# GCC: assembly listing for IA64 without an Itanium machine

Tags: compiler, assembly, gcc

I need to try the following thing: I would like to compile some simple C code samples and see the assembly listing generated by GCC for IA64 architecture, i.e. I just want to run GCC with the -S switch and see the resultant .s file. I don't have an Itanium machine, so in order to do it myself I'll probably need a cross-compiling version of GCC built for x86 RedHat. I'm not interested in full cross-compilation, meaning that I don't need to generate the binaries at all.

The easiest way, of course, would be to find an Itanium machine with with GCC and just try it there. Unfortunately, I don't seem to have access to any. Another option is to build a cross-compiling version GCC on my RedHat, but apparently that's quite an endeavor for someone who hasn't done it before (I assume that the fact that I only need .s output doesn't make it simpler).

What other options are there, if any? Maybe there's some sort of a web front to an Itanium GCC compiler on the Net (something like Comeau Online or ideone.com, but with .s output)? Anything else? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

umm, building a cross-compile tool-chain is not that hard. If you do binutils together with gcc, figuring out the configuration options is the only hard part. See cross-compiled linux from scratch for some ideas.

Comment: binutils won't be necessary to get an assembly listing from gcc. That gets rid of the hardest part.

Answer (score 0):

I believe VS2010 Ultimate comes with an IA64 compiler (you might have to install the Windows SDK).  It might be marginally easier than building the GCC toolchain (although I did this for the MSP430 on a Linux box and it wasn't too painful).